# `babel-runtime/core-js/object/entries` happens when `truffle test`

Tags: node.js, truffle

Can anyone help me with this issue for `truffle test`?

This is my environment:

```
Truffle v5.5.12 (core: 5.5.12)
Ganache v^7.1.0
Solidity - 0.8.13 (solc-js)
Node v17.9.0
Web3.js v1.5.3
```

This error `Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/core-js/object/entries'` happens when I `truffle test`

```
Using network 'development'.

Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/core-js/object/entries'
Require stack:
- /home/jh/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/reselect-tree/index.js
- /home/jh/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/debugger.js
- /home/jh/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jh/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/reselect-tree/external "babel-runtime/core-js/object/entries":1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/jh/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/reselect-tree/webpack/bootstrap e958f07978aa008e523d:19:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jh/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/reselect-tree/index.js:87:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/jh/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/reselect-tree/webpack/bootstrap e958f07978aa008e523d:19:1)
    at /home/jh/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/reselect-tree/webpack/bootstrap e958f07978aa008e523d:62:1
    at /home/jh/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/reselect-tree/index.js:76:10
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (/home/jh/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/reselect-tree/webpack/universalModuleDefinition:3:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jh/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/reselect-tree/webpack/universalModuleDefinition:10:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
Truffle v5.5.12 (core: 5.5.12)
Node v17.9.0
```

Comment: same issue for me, any luck from your side?

Comment: This also works for me
`npm install -g babel-runtime`


Original answer https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/5074

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem and it is most probably caused by the latest update of `reselect-tree`. If you force it's version to `1.3.5` it works.

You can install truffle locally in the project and in `package.json` add the following:

```
"overrides": {
    "reselect-tree": "1.3.5"
}
```

Then reinstall packages and run truffle with npx (or yarn): `npx truffle test` or `yarn truffle test`