# Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/core-js/object/entries'

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, truffle

when i try to test truffle test file then i got this error
(using command truffle test)

Using network 'development'.

Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/core-js/object/entries'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\RahulMuwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\reselect-tree\index.js
- C:\Users\RahulMuwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules@truffle\debugger\dist\debugger.js
- C:\Users\RahulMuwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\RahulMuwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\reselect-tree\external "babel-runtime\core-js\object\entries":1:1)
  at **webpack_require** (C:\Users\RahulMuwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\reselect-tree\webpack\bootstrap e958f07978aa008e523d:19:1)
  at Object. (C:\Users\RahulMuwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\reselect-tree\index.js:87:16)
  at **webpack_require** (C:\Users\RahulMuwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\reselect-tree\webpack\bootstrap e958f07978aa008e523d:19:1)
  at C:\Users\RahulMuwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\reselect-tree\webpack\bootstrap e958f07978aa008e523d:62:1
  at C:\Users\RahulMuwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\reselect-tree\index.js:76:10
  at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (C:\Users\RahulMuwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\reselect-tree\webpack\universalModuleDefinition:3:1)
  at Object. (C:\Users\RahulMuwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\reselect-tree\webpack\universalModuleDefinition:10:1)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  Truffle v5.5.0 (core: 5.5.0)
  Node v16.13.2

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue, I've opened an issue on github:
https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/5074

The only solution I founded, for now, it's to downgrade truffle to last v4 (4.1.17)

EDIT: it's also possible to install babel-runtime as a global package to make it work (`npm i -g babel-runtime`).

See github issue for more updates, they have fixed it! Soon will be released.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72096082/babel-runtime-core-js-object-entries-happens-when-truffle-test

Comment: How do you downgrade truffle?

Comment: Uninstall current version (`npm uninstall -g truffle`) and install the specific version (`npm i -g truffle@4.1.17`). You can also use the last version installing babel-runtime globally as a workaorund, see github issue

Comment: yeah npm i -D babel-runtime fixed it, I installed it locally and as dev dependency